# How to make a tree like based structured conversational action on google?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I want to make an action which ask user a question and answers in yes or no. The answers affect the future of player and gets different questions according to the user answers. And also I want to store the state so that user may resume afterwards. I think a binary tree like structure will work but how implement this in dialogflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two primary ways to do this.

The first way is to use [contexts](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts), which can be dynamically configured to limit the types of intents that can be triggered. This would allow you to develop a tree-like structure in a very precise way. However, this method would be more difficult to manage as you scale.

The alternative is to store data like questions answered and difficulty in [session data](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data#save_data_between_turns_of_a_conversation) and have a single Dialogflow intent that is able to capture the user's answer, give them a pass/fail, and provide the next question.

```
app.intent('My Question', (conv, {answer}) => {
  const {currentQuestion} = conv.data
  if (currentQuestion.answer === answer) {
    conv.ask('Correct!')
    conv.data.difficulty++
  } else {
    conv.ask('Wrong!')
    conv.data.difficulty--
  }
  const nextQuestion = customShuffle(conv.data.allQuestions, conv.data.difficulty)
  conv.data.allQuestions[nextQuestion.id] = undefined
  conv.ask('Next question! ' + nextQuestion.question)
})
```